# Errors during submitting iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to submit an application , and I am getting this issues

> Your app contains non-public API usage. Please review the errors,
>   correct them, and resubmit your application.
>
> The app references non-public symbols in Payload/XXX.app/XXX: 
>   CTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber

How can I solve these issues to continue submitting my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty clear.  Search your code for this

```
CTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber
```

Wherever you see it, whatever you are doing with it, you are not allowed to.  It is not a public api offered by Apple and thus against the agreement you have with them as a Developer for the App Store.

There is no way around submitting to the store with it, you must remove it, end of story.

Edit:  To make it clear why this would not be allowed by Apple.  I could, for example, release an app that gathers phone numbers without the users knowledge.  I then use those phone numbers to sell to companies as leads, etc.

Comment: I did before and searched in my project then I removed it but issues appear again during submission

Comment: If you removed all instances of it, make sure that you are re archiving the new code and submitting that new archive, not a previous one on accident.